# Error Message: The page contains too many server redirects

Tags: android, joomla

I have a website that I want my android visitors to see.  It is created in Joomla 1.5.  The problem is that sometimes I get the message "The page contains too many server redirects" on my G1.  Does anyone know what this means or how I can fix the problem?

Comment: I'm also faced with this behaviour which seems to be a bug within the android browser prior to version 2.2. We confirmed the server only sends one redirect message, but the error popup appears nevertheless. A workaround seems to be to just delete the browsers cache (and maybe history and cookies) and to try again. Anyhow, a permanent solution from a web developer perspective would be really great.

Answer (score 1):

Can you access it normally in a desktop? I'd say that the page is probably executing a redirect in a loop.

I am guessing (without knowing Joomla at all) that this is caused by bad routing rules (or maybe .htaccess). One url redirects to itself, causing the endless loop.

Comment: Access via a desktop browser works fine.  I think you are on the right track though because I am including joomla modules inside the page.

Comment: Actually to be precise, I am including the login module inside an Article.  When I press the back button I get this error message, paybe it is something to do with posting twice...causing an infinite loop somehow.